# Proof of $(A \setminus B)\setminus C = (A \setminus C) \setminus (B \setminus C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A,B,C$ be sets, show that then $(A \setminus B)\setminus C = (A \setminus C) \setminus (B \setminus C)$.

Using laws of associativity, distribution, De Morgan, I need to show this identity holds.

I think my final destination is:

$(A \cap B^\mathsf{c}) \cap (B \cap C^\mathsf{c})$

I am following these steps:
\begin{align}
(A \setminus B) \setminus C &=\\
(A \cap B^\mathsf{c}) \cap C^\mathsf{c} &=
\end{align}

Would appreciate any help about this proof.

Comment: Try to write each of the $-$ signs in set notation. For two sets, $X - Y$ is what as sets? That is, it contains all elements that are in $X$ but not in $Y$, but how can you write this with union/intersection? If you do this, you can simplify what you get with De Morgan maybe.

Comment: DeMorgan:  $(B\cap C)^C=B^C\cup C^C$

Comment: I don't think you want $B^C \cap B = \phi$

Comment: The LHS is correct : $A \cap B^\mathsf{c} \cap C^\mathsf{c}$.

Comment: The RHS is $(A \cap C^\mathsf{c}) \cap (B \cap C^\mathsf{c})^\mathsf{c}$ and using De Morgan : $(A \cap C^\mathsf{c}) \cap (B^\mathsf{c} \cup C)$

Comment: Now apply Distributivity and check that one of the two "terms" contains $C \cap C^\mathsf{c}$

Comment: I reached this stage: $A \cap C^\mathsf{c} \cap B^\mathsf{c} \cap C^\mathsf{c}$ on LHS.

Comment: I need to get a B, not B complement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
(A - C) - (B - C) &=
(A \cap C^\mathsf{c})  \cap (B \cap C^\mathsf{c})^\mathsf{c}\\
&=(A \cap C^\mathsf{c})  \cap (B^\mathsf{c} \cup C)\\
&=[(A \cap C^\mathsf{c})  \cap B^\mathsf{c}] \cup [(A \cap C^\mathsf{c})  \cap C]\\
&=[A \cap C^\mathsf{c} \cap B^\mathsf{c}] \cup [\emptyset]\\
&=A \cap C^\mathsf{c} \cap B^\mathsf{c}\\
&=[A \cap B^\mathsf{c}] \cap C^\mathsf{c}\\
&=[A - B] - C
\end{align}
I have implicitly used the associative property of union and intersection.
Also if you just want the validity of the statement, you can just use Venn's diagram without doing this long proof.

Comment: On the first (and second) line, don't you mean $(B\cap C^C)^C$?

Comment: Also, why didn't you say $[A \cap B^C] \cap C^C$ on the penultimate line?

Comment: @Tanner, yes I have edited it now.

Comment: I would appreciate if you edit my solution so that it also includes where I used what property.